# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in home/search.php on line 65

Tags: php, html, sql

What's going on here? Why won't it run? I've tried to look through the code for simple errors, and don't see any -- I've also looked through the forums. Nothing!

Is there something simple that I'm forgetting?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
        <style type='text/css">

        table {
            background-color: #FCF;
            }

        th {    
        width: 150px;
        text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Search</h1>


<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<label> Search | Category:
<select name="category">
    <option value="date">Date</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="account">Account</option>
                <option value="notes">Notes</option>
</select>
</label>

<label>Search Criteria: <input type="text" name="criteria" /></label>
<input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php
if  (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

// connect to DB
include('connectdb.php');

$category = $_POST['category'];
$criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE $category = '$category'";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbcon, $query) or die ('Error');

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Date</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Account</th> <th>Notes</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['date'];
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['name'];
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['account'];  
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['notes'];    
echo "</table>";

?>
</body></html>
}
```

Comment: HINT: Check your `{` and `}`.

Comment: It is good practice to tab your SQL in curly brackets... Easier to tell when you end them.

Comment: *"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end"* – One gets to know this one "by heart." – Missing closing braces `}`. ;-) Change `?></body></html> }` to `} } ?></body></html>`

Answer (score 4):

You're missing ending curly brackets for both the `if()` statement and the `while()` statement.

There is a trailing curly bracket at the end of the code, but it is outside of the php tags.

Answer (score 0):

You closed your PHP tags before closing your braces. This should work.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['date'];
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['name'];
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['account'];  
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row ['notes'];    
echo "</table>";
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last three lines are off. You have a close bracket not in a PHP tag. Look at your source code and that should be the last thing you see. That error is because PHP did not see your close bracket ending the `if`.