# PHP/HTML site shows up EMPTY when I execute it. No errors, just empty

Tags: php, mysql

I keep running into a blank page! Everytime I attempt to visit the site, it's blank! This is supposed to be a simple SQL retrieval page (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYmS5HRo6JI) but it just won't work. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            background-color: #FCF;
        }

        th {
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Search</h1>


<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

    <label> Search | Category:
        <select name="category">
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label>Search Criteria: <input type="text" name="criteria"/></label>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // connect to DB
    include('connect.php');

    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE $category = '$category'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die ('Error');


    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Date</th> <th>Name</th>";
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row ['date'];
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row ['name'];
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in home/search.php on line 65](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575670/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-in-home-search-php-on-line-65)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and a blank page usually means a fatal error killed your script, and you've got display_errors/error_reporting turned off.

Comment: Check the error log. You probably just have error set to not display.

Answer (score 0):

I completely removed the

```
<style...
```

from the head and it started displaying.

Here is the complete code I used that displayed properly:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Search</h1>


<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<label> Search | Category:
<select name="category">
<option value="name">Name</option>
<option value="date">Date</option>
</select>
</label>

<label>Search Criteria: <input type="text" name="criteria" /></label>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: removing the style did make it visible, however, I have an error at:  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

Comment: It says"  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in "  any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like your $mysql_result is equal to null.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Take a closer look at *mysqli_num_rows*.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            background-color: #FCF;
        }

        th {
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Search</h1>


<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

    <label> Search | Category:
        <select name="category">
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label>Search Criteria: <input type="text" name="criteria"/></label>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // connect to DB
    include('connect.php');

    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $criteria = $_POST['criteria'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE $category = '$category'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die ('Error');


    echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Date</th>";
                echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>" . $row['date'] . "</th>";
                        echo "<th>" . $row['name'] . "</th>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```